# ¿Existe una versión del "color carne" que no se refiera al color de piel de un grupo determinado de personas?

Tags: vocabulario, ambigüedad, colores

Algo obvio en el año que corre es que el *color carne* se refiere a un color similar al de la piel de algunas personas, pero no de todas. Por eso me gustaría saber si existe alguna denominación "estándar" para este color, que no se base en colores de piel.
[image: Color Carne]

Comment: Yo soy chileno y acá diríamos "color piel", que adivino que también lo encontrarás racista. Como no lo uso, "carne" me suena más al color de la que venden en las carnicerías.

Comment: Sí, viene siendo lo mismo, *piel* y *carne* son sinónimos en algunos casos, por lo que no sirve de demasiado.

Comment: A mí no me parece racista, sino consecuencia de un uso en un lugar: se refiere a un color que identificaba el de la carne sonrosada de la mayoría de la gente en un momento dado. Dudo que una persona negra pueda sentirse ofendida cuando se asocia "color carne" a una que no es la suya.

Comment: Yo me sentiría ofendido si mis compañeros, de pelo rubio, se refirieran a su color de pelo como *color pelo* mientras el mío es el castaño y no existiendo la palabra *rubio* (algo genérico) con la que poder hacer referencia a su color de pelo.

Comment: Creo que la solución es a la inversa. En vez de cambiarle el nombre al color hay que "ensanchar" el rango de los tonos.

Comment: @Rodrigo pues sí, pero entonces dejaría de tener sentido, ya que si el color carne hiciera referencia desde las pieles más claras a las más oscuras, que pintaría el color *negro* si existe el color *carne muy oscura* o lo mismo con el *marrón* y un sin fin de ejemplos. De todos modos, no intento cambiar la RAE, solo saber si existe una solución.

Comment: "color carne blanca"?

Comment: pues qué tal si lo llamamos color maquillaje?, esos colores me hace recordar a los colores que están presentes en los set de maquillaje

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16735/existe-una-versión-del-color-carne-no-racista Amarillo nápoles rojizo

Comment: color arena diría yo.

Comment: Algunos nombres de colores utilizados en el diseño web desde los más claros hasta los más oscuros: "Linen","PapayaWhip","AntiqueWhite","BlanchedAlmond","PeachPuff","Moccasin","NavajoWhite","Wheat","BurlyWood","Tan","SandyBrown","Peru"

Comment: No es racista, es histórico. Los nombres de los colores a menudo se eligen arbitrariamente por razones históricas.

Comment: @Quidam siendo la historia como ha sido, a lo mejor su procedencia si que es de carácter racista, no?

Comment: Esta pregunta es interesante (en mi opinión) pero está recibiendo votos de cierre porque la alusión al racismo se está interpretando como "opinion based". Elimino las referencias al racismo en un intento de salvar la pregunta y eliminar la controversia. A fin de cuentas, Spanish.SE es para discutir puramente el lenguage español.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: este es el color durazno claro]

Yo siempre he dicho color carne, hasta hoy, porque me he estado informando y no creo que deba ser así.
He mirado opiniones, ideas y gamas de colores y creo que el color **durazno claro** es el mismo o muy parecido a mi antiguo carne. Espero que sea de ayuda :)

También he visto gente que le llama **color crema** o **color beige / beis**.

Comment: Si existe ese color en España sería "melocotón claro" porque no usamos la palabra _durazno_

Comment: @nadie: En Tenerife (probablemente también en las otras islas Canarias) sí que se usa la palabra "durazno" (mis abuelos maternos eran de allí y la usaban). De todas formas, al color de la imagen yo lo llamaría "color salmón".

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre el *beige* (o [beis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5IPkO8W)), como algo lo suficientemente vago para denominar a bastantes de esos colores.

[image: Beige shades]

De pequeño en la escuela le llamábamos color carne a los crayones rosados más claros que el color salmón. Siempre pensé que el nombre se refería a la carne de los filetes.

Fuente de la imagen: [The awesomeness of beige](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/09/the-awesomeness-of-beige/).

Comment: El problema es que el beis hace referencia también a otra gama de colores y no específicamente a la del color "carne"

Comment: ¿Y beis + adjetivo? De otra manera no se me ocurre nada si no.

Comment: Estaba buscando por una palabra concreta. A mi tampoco se me ocurre nada y buscando, lo único que me encuentro son sugerencias, nada más.

Answer (score 2):

beige, café/marrón claro...
 Creo que será difícil encontrar una palabra que abarque todos los colores de piel, porque incluso en el rango que tú presentas hay mucha variación, desde "caramelo" hasta "avena". Creo que valdría la pena reformular para qué necesitas una palabra que los abarque a esos y sólo a esos, o utilizar un término genérico que los incluya a todos.

Comment: Lo de la imagen era más bien como ejemplo, haciendo referencia a que estoy hablando de ese tipo de colores cuando digo *color carne*. Sin más me gustaría saber si existe un término genérico para denominar dicho color.

Answer (score 2):

Soy una de esas personas que han crecido llamando a este color "color carne" y que se han dado cuenta (en mi caso hace ya algunos años) de lo discriminatorio que es hacerlo así.

Personalmente creo que **lo más sencillo es** dejar de usar "color carne" o "color piel" a secas, y **especificar siempre el tono**: "color piel morena", "color piel blanca", "color piel rosada", "color piel negra", "color piel aceituna", etc.

Existen [iniciativas con éxito](https://www.verkami.com/projects/15996-pintemos-los-colores-de-la-piel) que promulgan llamar "color piel" a toda la gama de colores de la piel humana, lo cual me parece perfecto.

Ahora bien, si lo que nos ofende no es solo que se asuma que la piel "normal" es la de nuestro mismo color, sino insinuar siquiera que las pieles pueden ser de colores diferentes, entonces hay que pasar a usar colores [Pantone](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantone) o alguna otra denominación oficial o basada en colores naturales. Por ejemplo: [siena](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siena_(color)) u [ocre](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocre), [rosado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_(color)), [ébano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89bano), [marrón o café](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marr%C3%B3n)...

En el caso concreto del color "carne", el equivalente sería "**rosa anaranjado**".

Comment: Comparto tu opinión.  Pero igual *color piel* seguiría valiendo, en el caso de haber un contexto claro.  Por ejemplo, si estamos retratando a alguien y queremos describir algún objeto en el fondo, color piel equivaldría directamente al color de la persona retratada (que podría variar muchísimo)

Comment: Ups. Quería decir color carne, tuve un lapsus mental :-)

Comment: @guifa en algunos lugares moreno es considerado negro, y otros trigueño tipo indio...depende de la region

Answer (score 0):

Al igual que cada color tiene una subpaleta de matices, creo que el color piel también las tiene. Por supuesto dependiendo del color de nuestra propia piel y del color de la piel de las personas de nuestro entorno cada uno se identificará con diferentes matices de este color. De esta forma todos usamos el color piel, pero dependiendo de nosotros y de nuestro entorno el matiz con el cual nos identificaremos, así las personas pertenecientes a diferentes grupos culturales, geográficos o étnicos como: asiáticos, africanos, latinos, mediterráneos, albinos, caucásicos, etc etc etc, tomarán el color piel en algún matíz diferente de este. 
Creo que el cambio se debe hacer en dos fases, la primera comprender el color piel como un grupo de matices, el segundo culturalmente al comprender que cuando se hable de color piel se habla de dicho grupo de matices y no te un color en específico.
Expuesta mi postura, quiero agregar que para dicho fin existe la Escala cromática von Luschan o Escala de von Luschan.

[https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escala_cromática_de_Von_Luschan](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escala_crom%C3%A1tica_de_Von_Luschan)

Dicha escala fue significativamente ampliada por diferentes fabricantes y diseñadores de maquillaje incluyendo sub matices.

Answer (score -1):

Según el color del lápiz si es rosa anaranjado o rosa pastel simplemente decirle color beige y si es rosa claro, decirle rosado pálido

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Spanish.SE. Thank you for your contribution, but I encourage you to visit the Tour and Help sections and learn a little bit more about how we work on this site. You answer does not really address the question. Maybe you should ellaborate a little bit more. Also, please take into account the colors included in the question.